# Showing bijectivity of a map - group-isomorphism

Tags: group-isomorphism, bilinear-form

I have an exercise on group isomorphisms but I do not quite understand the second part of their proof.

Assume that $B$ is a symmetric bilinear form, and let $q : V \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map given by $q(u) = \frac{1}{2}B(u, u)$.

Show that the map $\phi : G \to G$, given by $\phi(u, a) = (u, a + q(u))$ for $u \in V$
and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a group-isomorphism.

I have showed that it is compatible with composition laws. For bijectivity:

Injectivity I could show by showing $\ker(\phi)=(0,0)$,

so $(u,a+\frac{1}{2}B(u, u))=(0,0) \Rightarrow u = 0$

and $a+\frac{1}{2}B(u, u)=0$

Since $u = 0$ we know that  $\frac{1}{2}B(u, u) = 0$ and therefore $a = 0$

For surjectivity however, I do not quite understand the proof.

Since $\phi(u,a-q(u))=(u,a)$, every element of $G$ is in the image of $\phi$.

What are the steps to get this solution? Is there some intermediate step that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\phi$, we have
$$
\phi(u,a-q(u)) = \big(u,(a-q(u))+q(u)\big) = (u,a).
$$
It remains to show that $(u,a-q(u)) \in G$, but I'm not sure how $G$ is defined, so give that a try yourself! What you have then shown is that every element of $G$ is the image of some other element in $G$ under $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. However, how did you come up with that solution? Is there a trick to it or just practice? I don't think I could solve this without any help from a solution.

Comment: In this case, you're looking for some $b \in G$ such that $\phi(u,b)=(u,a)$, i.e. you can simply set (by definition of $\phi$) $\phi(u,b)=(u,a)$, i.e. you get $b + q(u) = a$, since nothing changes in the first coordinate. Then, if you solve for $b$, you get $b = a-q(u)$, as in the solution. It is indeed mostly practice, though. Sometimes the solution presents itself right away, and sometimes I get stuck as well. Glad I could help!

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot. Actually I tried solving it similarly to the way you just said but thought I did not get anywhere. Thank you for your help I'll keep trying